# Implementing an app with multiple views in GWT

Tags: gwt

I understand from threads in this forum and the Google GWT forum that in the GWT world you typically load just a single page and then what appears to a user to be a different page is just the same page with it's content being updated by user actions. A lot of posts imply that you develop your app as you would a desktop application.  That sounds easy if you have done desktop development but I am coming from a pure Web services/ Servlets/ Struts background and want to see a very basic example that shows the proper way to implement a GWT app where you show a user a txt box and button and when they click the button,  the view is replaced with 2 different components.
There are plenty of basic apps I have done and plenty of complex multipage type ones but I just one that takes me past the click a button to see a message type app to the next level.
Any links to such an example would be welcome

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.cm/questions/1061705/multiple-pages-tutorial-in-google-web-toolkit-gwt

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to study [Activities & Places design pattern](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces). It is the best approach, in my view, for large applications with multiple views. It provides a lot of important functionality "out of the box", like browser history management, support for tokens, efficient memory management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the Model-View-Presenter pattern (MVP). Using this pattern correctly will greatly decouple your application, allowing you to create views that are not only highly modular and disposable, but are very easy to swap out and change.

In fact, Google fully recommends the MVP pattern when developing GWT applications. They provide a full example and walkthrough of a MVP GWT application [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture), which I imagine is based off of a [Google I/O presentation](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) given on best GWT application architecture practices back in 2009.

I've been following this pattern with my latest GWT project and it's working out extremely well. It's very easy to add, remove and swap views.